# "Антон ждёт Анну" or "Антон ждёт Анны"?

Tags: падежи

In a Russian language book called Поехали, there's an exercise where we are supposed to be complete a sentence, and we get: "Антон ждёт Анну".

I would translate this sentence as "Anton awaits / waits for Anna".

However, I consulted [this wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), and it's stated that we should use the genitive case. This doesn't seem to be in accordance with the sentence above, since "Анну" is the accusative case... I would understand if we were dealing with a male person, since then the genitive and accusative would be equal, but in this case Анна is a female.

Comment: ok, I've reread it twice and came to conclusion that this can cause confusion even if referencing sources, so I've reopened. Will answer if it won't get enough attention in couple of hours - otherwise it can look like unfair competition - closing question, than re-opening it and immediately answering. Also, keep in mind that wiktionary is a very good starting point but not always 100% reliable - it's wiki after all.

Comment: @shabunc Do you know of another dictionary which also gives you the cases you use when consulting a verb entry in it? I'm always looking for one.

Comment: in this particular case you can google by "управление глагола ждать" - most of links would lead your to the patriarch of Russian grammar references, Дитмар Эльяшевич Розенталь )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It's `ждёт Анну` since he not just waiting for any arbitrary Anna ;)**

The thing is that "ждать" is governed by both Genitive and Accusative in Russian, depending on context. When you use "ждать" with some abstract noun, then it's Genitive, for instance:

- **Ждать поезда** - to wait for a train.
- **Ждать письма** - to wait for a letter.
- **Ждать удачи** - to wait for success.

When you use with some noun that in English most likely will be used with "the", that is, with something that is called in Russian reference "cуществительное с оттенком определённости" (with connotation of definitiveness), then it's Accusative, like in:

- **Ждать поезд** [Москва-Анапа] - to wait for the train.
- **Ждать письмо** [от сестры] - to wait for the letter.

Keep in mind that in colloquial speech some of the phrases are used interchangeably, the difference is very subtle. One can say "ждать удачу" or "ждать письма" while meaning some specific letter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and comment. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The verbs ждать and ожидать can require both cases: genitive and accusative.
In case with a noun describing something **animate**, always use **accusative**.

Я ждал свою девушку( Анну, брата, собаку).

When the subject is **inanimate and concrete**, use **accusative**.

Я стоял на платформе, ожидая московский поезд.

Otherwise use genitive (see the previous answer)

Не жди от него писем, не жди.

Источник: грамота.ру